# Regex to match text after a given character excluding the character itself

Tags: regex

Consider the following text -

```
[Event "F/S Return Match"]
```

I want to extract -

```
F/S Return Match
```

Right now I'm using -

```
\"(.*)"
```

Which yeilds -

```
"F/S Return Match"
```

Then I use -

```
[^"]*
```

To get -

```
F/S Return Match
```

Could I combine the two into one?

Comment: yes you can combine, you could also use `"(.*)"` alone, [**see a DEMO of it here.**](http://rubular.com/r/Yj9U1RFExZ)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[Look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) could be an option:**

```
(?<=")[^"]*(?=")
```

`(?<=")` checks that the previous character is a `"`.
`(?=")` checks that the next character is a `"`.

[Test](http://www.rubular.com/r/mc0it7Slfl).

**An alternative is just to use [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):**

```
"([^"]*)"
```

How to extract the group is dependent on the language used.

[Test](http://www.rubular.com/r/M11FhF5H5R). (note the "Matching groups" area)

I didn't simply use `"(.*)"` because the string `abc "def" "ghi"` will match `"def" "ghi"`, though you may have wanted to match `"def"` and `"ghi"` separately. An alternative to `[^"]` is non-greedy matching - `"(.*?)"`, which will match as little of the string as possible.

Comment: As far as I know, JavaScript doesn't support look-behind.

Comment: Yes, it is language dependent. The main differences I know of is look-around support, some complex group operations support and minor group syntax differences. Though I think I've seen some languages doing something completely different. [It seems Python supports it](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).